# Keras Can't Add similar shapes together

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, addition, layer

I am trying to build an Inception model as described here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-time-series-classification-inceptiontime-245703f422db

It all works so far, but when I try to implement the shortcut layer and add the two tensors together I get an Error.

Here is my shortcut code:

```
def shortcut_layer(inputs,z_interception):
    print(inputs.shape)
    inputs = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=int(z_interception.shape[-1]),kernel_size=1,padding='same',use_bias=False)(inputs)

    print(z_interception.shape[-1])
    print(inputs.shape,z_interception.shape)
    inputs = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    
    z = keras.layers.Add()([inputs,z_interception])
    print('zshape: ',z.shape)
    
    return keras.layers.Activation('relu')(z)
```

The output is as follows:
(None, 160, 8)
128
(None, 160, 128) (None, 160, 128)

The output is exactly as I expect it to be, but I still get the error:

ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (160, 128) (160, 8)

which doesn't make sense to me as I try to add the two tensors with shape: (None, 160, 128)

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is `(160,128)` and `(160,8)` are "similar" shapes? To perform element wise addition it should be something like `(160, 128)` and `(160,128)` or `(160, 128)` and `(160,1)` , etc.

Comment: After the Conv1D the shapes are (160, 128) and (160, 128).